# accessing elements in simplejson.load() output

Tags: python, json, simplejson

i have a dictionary(?) of data returned from the simplejson.load() function.  it looks like this...

```
{'status': 'OK', 'results': [{'geometry': {'location_type': 'APPROXIMATE', 'bounds': {'northeast': {'lat': 53.86121, 'lng': -2.045072}, 'southwest': {'lat': 53.80570600000001, 'lng': -2.162588}}, 'viewport': {'northeast': {'lat': 53.8697753, 'lng': -2.0725853}, 'southwest': {'lat': 53.81711019999999, 'lng': -2.2006447}}, 'location': {'lat': 53.84345099999999, 'lng': -2.136615}}, 'address_components': [{'long_name': 'Trawden', 'types': ['sublocality', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Trawden'}, {'long_name': 'Colne', 'types': ['locality', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Colne'}, {'long_name': 'Lancashire', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political'], 'short_name': 'Lancs'}, {'long_name': 'United Kingdom', 'types': ['country', 'political'], 'short_name': 'GB'}], 'formatted_address': 'Trawden, Colne, Lancashire, UK', 'types': ['sublocality', 'political']}]}
```

How do I get at e.g. results->geometry->location->lat ?

Is this structure a regular python dictionary?

EDIT: please could someone also explain the simplejson.dumps() function.  I don't find the docs very enlightening.

thanks

Edit by non-OP: here's the JSON, pretty-printed:

```
{
  "status":"OK",
  "results":[
    {
      "geometry":{
        "location":{
          "lat":53.843450999999988,
          "lng":-2.1366149999999999
        },
        "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":53.869775300000001,
            "lng":-2.0725853000000001
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":53.817110199999988,
            "lng":-2.2006446999999998
          }
        },
        "bounds":{
          "northeast":{
            "lat":53.86121,
            "lng":-2.0450719999999998
          },
          "southwest":{
            "lat":53.805706000000008,
            "lng":-2.162588
          }
        }
      },
      "address_components":[
        {
          "long_name":"Trawden",
          "short_name":"Trawden",
          "types":[
            "sublocality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Colne",
          "short_name":"Colne",
          "types":[
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"Lancashire",
          "short_name":"Lancs",
          "types":[
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name":"United Kingdom",
          "short_name":"GB",
          "types":[
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address":"Trawden, Colne, Lancashire, UK",
      "types":[
        "sublocality",
        "political"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. If you store it in a variable named `d`, then you would use...

```
d['results'][0]['geometry']['location']
```

et cetera. Notice the `[0]` there due to the fact that the dict with key `'geometry'` is inside a list.

`simplejson.load()` maps JSON objects to Python `dict`s and JSON lists to `list`s. Very straightforward; don't overthink it.

---

`simplejson.dumps()` simply does the opposite of `simplejson.loads()` - it takes any standard Python object, and dumps it to a string which is a JSON representation of that object. For instance:

```
>>> q = {}
>>> q['foo'] = 'bar'
>>> q[1] = 'baz'
>>> simplejson.dumps(q)
'{"1": "baz", "foo": "bar"}'
```

Comment: Read the edited post. :) See how in your data, it says `'results': [{'geometry':`... and so on? See how there's both a `[` and a `{` before `'geometry'`? That's because that particular part of the structure actually looks like this: `{'A': [{'B': 'C'}]}` which is a dict-inside-a-list-inside-a-dict.

Comment: thanks for the great answer, sorry to bother but some of the syntax is confusing the hell out of me.  e.g. in the google example they get the data like so...    `[s['geometry']['location'] for s in json['results']]`  What is this?!

Comment: That's a list comprehension. Here's a reasonable overview of them: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk (or the official docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: cool thanks.  Is it better to use this method because it does not rely on the fixed [0] position?

Comment: The list comprehension returns a list, which if you wanted the first element in, you'd still have to use a `[0]` to get at. Just depends on what data you expect to get.